# Sub-Menu item disappears after appearing briefly on click of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am new here.
I have a WordPress site http://invitroplanttech.se/products/ . When the products menu item is clicked, the sub-menu items disappears after appearing briefly. ALso, clicking the menu item causes re-loading of the page

When I clicked on product sub-menu appear and go, but I need to sub-menu goes sometime late.
Here is jquery  code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.home').addClass('current-menu-item');
        $('.navigation ul ul li a').hide();
        $(".navigation ul li:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
           $('.navigation ul ul li a').show();
           setTimeout( "jQuery('.navigation ul ul li a').hide();",10000 );  

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

### About your code

The problem why your menu "flashes"/appears only a few moment is because you listen to the click on `<li>` but you let `<a>` event being thrown. All common browsers load a new page when you click on a `<a>`tag which has a valid `@href` attribute.

With your code, when you click on this `<li>` you also click on `<a>` which reload the page and hide your menu.

To avoid that reload, you need to stop the event on `<a>` tag by returning `false` (see the code below).

### The JQuery solution

I made [a JSFiddle with your HTML code](http://jsfiddle.net/KY5JQ/1/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.navigation li').has('> ul').children('a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

### You can do a submenu easily via CSS

```
.navigation li ul { display: none; }
.navigation li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

This is very easy way which does not need to load a full library as JQuery and works fine on all recent browsers.

The difference with your demand is that you can not handle "click" easily, that's why this example do it on over.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours , try to put `'#' in your href tag` inside your "li" element.

```
  <li id="your_button_id"><a href="#">Item Name</a></li>
```

In your javascript add,

```
$("#your_button_id").click(function(e) {
                $('#display_menu1').css({"display":"block"});
                $('#display_menu2').css({"display":"none"});


            });
```